# Is $\{3\}$ a subset of $\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $\{3\}$ a subset of $\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$?

If the set contained $\{3\}$ plain and simply I would know but does the element $\{1,2,3\}$ include $\{3\}$ such that it would be a subset?

Comment: No, it's not. Let $A=\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$. The subsets must themselves contain sets, since A is a set of sets. Then $\{\{1\}\}$ is a subset of A, $\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$ is another subset of A. $\{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ is also a subset of A. $\{3\}$ is a subset of an element of A.

Comment: No, when you have a set of sets, you do not "look through" the brackets.  The sets are members, but the members of those sets are not members.

Comment: [Similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838707/subset-of-a-set-of-sets)

Comment: "Is $3=\{1\}$?" **;** "Is $3=\{1,2\}$?" **;** "Is $3=\{1,2,3\}$?": If the answer to one of these questions is *yes*, then $\{3\}$ is a subset of $\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$; otherwise, it isn't.

Comment: @Gae.S.And it should be noted that the answer *may* be yes!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen it *may* be yes.  but it isn't.  At least in no set theory and natural number definitions that i'm aware of.

Comment: Maybe the simplest way to put this is there is a common misconception that if $a \in B$ and $B \in \Omega$ that that might somehow means $a \in \Omega$.  And that is *not* the case.  Membership is not transitive and does not carry over hierarchies.  So $3 \in \{1,2,3\} $ and $\{1,2,3\} \in \{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ does not mean $3 \in \{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a set. We say $Y \subseteq X$ ($Y$ is a subset of $X$) if, for all $x \in Y$, we have $x \in X$.

Examine the sets $Y = \{3\}$, $X = \{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$. Take $x = 3 \in Y$. Is $3 \in X$?

Trickier problem: If $X = \{\{1\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$, is $3 \in X$?

Comment: Why is the trickier problem trickier?  $3\not \in X$ because $3\ne \{1\};3\ne \{3\},3\ne \{1,2\}, 3\ne \{1,2,3\}$.  Why is that trickier.

Comment: I would expect someone to say "Oh, I see 3 by itself" and say it is in the set. I wanted to emphasize the difference between $\{3\}$ and $3$.

Answer (score 1):

No.

the elements inside elements of the set do not count.

The elments of your big set are:

- $\{1\}$
- $\{1,2\}$
- $\{1,2,3\}$.

The elements of your small set are:

- $3$

So $\{3\}$ is a subset only if $3$ is equal (the *same* thing; !!!!!***NOT***!!!! an element within) one of the elements $\{1\}$ or $\{1,2\}$, or $\{1,2,3\}$.  But none of those are the same thing as $3$ so $\{3\}$ is not a subset.

But in some text the natural numbers are defined as

$0 = \emptyset$

$1= \{\emptyset\}$

$2= \{\emptyset, 1\}$.

$3 = \{\emptyset, 1, 2\}$

So we could have a trick thing of $\{3\} \subset \{\{\emptyset,1\}, \{\emptyset,1,2\}, \{\emptyset,1,2,3\}\}$ *not* because $3 \in \{\emptyset,1,2,3\}$ (that's utterly irrelevent), but because $3 =  \{\emptyset, 1, 2\}$ and the set  $\{\{\emptyset,1\}, \{\emptyset,1,2\}, \{\emptyset,1,2,3\}\}$ is equally equal to the set $\{2,3,4\}$ and $\{3\}\subset \{2,3,4\}$.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not, we have that $\{1\}\in \{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ but $\{3\}$ is not an element of the set, what is true is that $3\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there are plenty of good answers here.

I think that the most important thing to understand is:

$$3 \neq \{ 3 \}.$$

These are two different objects.

Moreover the followings hold:

$$ 3 \in \{3\}$$
$$ 3 \in \{\ldots, 3, \ldots \}$$
$$\{3\} \in \{\ldots, \{3\}, \ldots\}$$
and

$$ \{3\} \not\in \{3\}$$
$$ \{3\} \not\in \{\ldots, 3, \ldots \}$$

Comment: In for a penny..... might as well add (and perhaps germaine to the common misconception) $3\not \in \{........., \{3\},......\}$  (unless it is one of the objects omitted in the "..."s.)